# Putting nested arrays through a reducer function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to put nested arrays from an Apollo RESTDataSource query through a reducer function which returns the data in the shape of my GraphQL schema. I need the data to remain nested since they are data pairs. A simplified version of the nested arrays is such:

```
const places = [
    [
        {
            lng: 'value1',
            lat: 'value2', 
            otherKey: 'otherValue'
        },
        {  
            lng: 'value1',
            lat: 'value2',
            otherKey: 'otherValue'
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            lng: 'value1',
            lat: 'value2',
            otherKey: 'otherValue'
        },
        {  
            lng: 'value1',
            lat: 'value2',
            otherKey: 'otherValue'
        }
    ]
]
```

A simplified version of my reducer function is:

```
reducerFn(places) {
    return {
        coordinates: [places.lng, places.lat]
    };
};
```

I want the reducer function to return an array of arrays where objects in the inner arrays are in the shape of the object returned in the reducer function.

I've tried to map the outer array and call the reducer function on the mapped array, as such:

```
return places.map(route => this.reducerFn(route))
```

But that returns a simple array of `null` values.

How would I return this?

```
[
    [
        {
            coordinates: [lng, lat]
        },
        {
            coordinates: [lng, lat]
        }
    ]
]
```

Comment: In `reducerFn(places)`, try wrapping the returned object in parentheses:
`return ({ coordinates: [places.lng, places.lat] });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to iterate over the `places` array and call [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method again on each nested array to iterate over the nested arrays and return new object with `coordinates` property.

```js
const places = [
  [
    { lng: 'value1', lat: 'value2', otherKey: 'otherValue' },
    { lng: 'value1', lat: 'value2', otherKey: 'otherValue' }
  ],
  [
    { lng: 'value1', lat: 'value2', otherKey: 'otherValue' },
    { lng: 'value1', lat: 'value2', otherKey: 'otherValue' },
  ]
];

function reducerFn(places) {
  return places.map(arr =>
    arr.map(obj => ({ coordinates: [obj.lng, obj.lat] }))
  );
}

console.log(reducerFn(places));
```

Comment: I had tried this, but this just returns ```coordinates: null```

Comment: You probably did something wrong. You can run the code snippet and see that `reducerFn` returns the expected output. Make sure the `places` array that you pass to reducer function is in the format that is specified in your question.

Comment: Fair, I'm going to need to see what I've done wrong, but I'll mark this answer as correct since it does exactly what I asked.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the values of `lng` and `lat` (and `otherKey`) to distinguish in result (`coordinates`).

```js
var places=[[{"lng":"lng1","lat":"lat1","otherKey":"otherValue1"},{"lng":"lng2","lat":"lat2","otherKey":"otherValue2"}],[{"lng":"lng3","lat":"lat3","otherKey":"otherValue3"},{"lng":"lng4","lat":"lat4","otherKey":"otherValue4"}]];

var coordinates=places.map(place=>
  place.map(p=>({coordinates: [p.lng, p.lat]}))
);

console.log(coordinates);
```